# Xcode 10 Broke Autocomplete When Inserting Include Names for C++, Any Workarounds?

Tags: xcode, include

I no longer get any autocompletion results when I begin to type a standard header file name in the include statements:

```
#include <>
```

Normally, typing in a name such as vector or string would cause the autocompletion list to open and display results for these library names, but it is not happening in Xcode 10. I'm getting some autocompletion results for other headers, but nothing related to the standard C++ libraries. Does anyone know any workarounds or solutions to this? I asked in the Apple developer forums, but I've received no help after a week now.

I know that directory for standard C++ library files is:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1
```

But I'm unaware where this would be placed in Xcode to hopefully get it to allow for autocompletion of headers for all projects in Xcode (and not just whatever specific project is loaded.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: They just can't get Xcode to work properly with C++, can they? Cannot fix something without breaking something else :( Sad and annoying.

Comment: Nothing fixed since 10.1.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is also the case with Objective-C too. And still not fixed in 10.1 either.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It worked before but now all of a sudden without changing anything, it doesn't show the standard library headers anymore. I can type them manually and it compiles and I can even click on them to go the header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the above mentioned path `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1`
to your project 'Build Settings' -> Header Search Paths -> Debug -> Any Architecture.

[image]

Comment: Its too bad there isn't a global fix for this.  Am I wrong in thinking it used to always autocomplete by default?

Comment: This solution also works for Xcode 11. My Xcode ran into same problem after being updated to Xcode 11. I just don't know why this happened. I think I haven't change any configuration and my other IDE or editor don't have this problem. Has it ever been mentioned in any release notes or something?

Comment: This is not working for me on Xcode 13 or 12. Is this still working for anyone? It's ridiculous that this a thing with Xcode...